# Wrong in promises, program opens and instantly closes

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, ytdl

Code ytdl.js

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core')
const fs = require('fs')

downloadAudio = link => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const stream = ytdl(link).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(`musica.mp3`));
        stream.on('error', () => {
            console.log('Tive problemas para baixar sua música!')
            reject();
        })
        stream.on('close', () => {
            console.log('Baixado!')
            resolve();
        })
    })
}
```

Code index.js

```js
const api = require('./ytdl')

api.downloadAudio('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I3A45smjVo4').then(()=>{
    console.log('Música baixada!')
}).catch(()=>{
    console.log('Tive algum problema para baixar sua música!')
})
```

Why when I compile the code does the system just shut down? Am I missing promises?

Obs: I'm a beginner, sorry.

Comment: what do you mean by system shut down? your computer shutdown? the program exit? what framework are you using?

Comment: Regarding the system output. The Console does not print anything. I'm using Node.js and Ytdl-core

Comment: Try adding return outside also. Reject or resolve. Maybe there is something else event other than 'close' and 'error' and which is why your promise is not returning anything.

Comment: Can you show me how this would be done please?

Comment: Resolved! Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `downloadAudio()` outside your module, you need to export it, otherwise the function is only available inside the module. That means that the call `api.downloadAudio` is `undefined` since `downloadAudio` does not exists outside the module.

So change the line

```
downloadAudio = link => {
```

to

```
exports.downloadAudio = link => {
```

More info can be found in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut).